# How to connect to a db on google cloud from mobile devices

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-sql

I need to deploy a web app with its postgreSQL db on google cloud platform. 
How can I connect to this db from mobile devices? I'm not allowed in this project to connect to db direct via mobile devices but via REST API.

So will I need to deploy also a REST API ex. in PHP, or Google Cloud has a REST API to access db from client devices?

Comment: You can use cloud endpoint framework for creating rest APIs in app-engine. Connect mysql in the endpoint. Follow their documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can connect to REST to PostgreSQL also Right?           The web app is Odoo app with its PostgreSQL.

Comment: Can I deploy a REST API built with PHP Slim Framework to Google endpoint framework and connect from it to db, and mobile devices connect to this REST API?

Comment: Look for the following example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/endpoints/getting-started

Comment: Can I deploy a REST API created with a php framework to google cloud platform instead of Google endpoints?